# How to compute the FAT size in FAT File System

Tags: c, fat32, fat

I am implementing a FAT file system in C. I am following the specs published by microsoft (http://read.pudn.com/downloads77/ebook/294884/FAT32%20Spec%20%28SDA%20Contribution%29.pdf)

But I don't understand how to compute the FAT size field of boot sector. In the specification document appear the following code on page 14.

```
RootDirSectors = ((BPB_RootEntCnt * 32) + (BPB_BytsPerSec – 1)) / BPB_BytsPerSec; 
TmpVal1 = DskSize – (BPB_ResvdSecCnt + RootDirSectors); 
TmpVal2 = (256 * BPB_SecPerClus) + BPB_NumFATs; 
If(FATType == FAT32) 
    TmpVal2 = TmpVal2 / 2; 
FATSz = (TMPVal1 + (TmpVal2 – 1)) / TmpVal2; 
If(FATType == FAT32) { 
    BPB_FATSz16 = 0; 
    BPB_FATSz32 = FATSz; 
} else { 
    BPB_FATSz16 = LOWORD(FATSz); 
    /* there is no BPB_FATSz32 in a FAT16 BPB */ 
}
```

From this code I don't understand

1. What is TmpVal2?
2. Why number 256 is used?
3. Why if it is FAT32 it divide by 2?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why the constant of 256 was chosen however here are some thoughts on your other questions.

There is a note below the source code segment which states that the math is an approximation.

> NOTE: The above math does not work perfectly. It will occasionally set
>   a FATSz that is up to 2 sectors too large for FAT16, and occasionally
>   up to 8 sectors too large for FAT32. It will never compute a FATSz
>   value that is too small, however. Because it is OK to have a FATSz
>   that is too large, at the expense of wasting a few sectors, the fact
>   that this computation is surprisingly simple more than makes up for it
>   being off in a safe way in some cases.

The way I read the code is that the calculation is for a FAT16 size and then there is an adjustment to the calculation if the target is actually FAT32.

The value of the variable `TmpVal2` looks to be a unit size in that the amount of space calculated for the value of `TmpVal1` is then divided by the unit size value of `TmpVal2` in order to determine the number of units of disk space. However in the case of FAT32 the unit size is smaller than in FAT16 so there needs to be an adjustment.

It appears that FAT16 used a specific size for the File Allocation Table and as the hard disk space available for a volume was increased with improvements in disk technology, the cluster size was based on the volume size. So with a smaller volume size the cluster size, the number of disk sectors in an allocation unit, was smaller than the cluster size for a large volume size. See [FAT16 vs. FAT32 in Microsoft TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940351.aspx) as well as the tables in the source code on page 13 of the document you reference.

With FAT32, a standard cluster size of 4K was used and the File Allocation Table storage was changed from a fixed size to a variable size and was no longer at a fixed location on the disk.

This artice, [File systems (FAT, FAT8, FAT16, FAT32, and NTFS) explained](https://www.pctechguide.com/hard-disks/file-systems-fat-fat8-fat16-fat32-and-ntfs-explained), goes into some details about the differences between these various file system versions.

The Wikipedia article, [File Allocation Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table), has quite a bit of technical information with links to other articles.

You may also find the following stackoverflow articles of interest.

[Converting the cluster number stored in FAT table (of FAT12 filesystem) for reading from a floppy disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785723/converting-the-cluster-number-stored-in-fat-table-of-fat12-filesystem-for-read?rq=1)

[Why did Windows use the FAT structure instead of a conventional linked list with a next pointer for each data block of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22422265/why-did-windows-use-the-fat-structure-instead-of-a-conventional-linked-list-with?rq=1)